# Как исправить ошибку «cannot find any CMake profile» при сборке проекта CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Раньше пользовался VS, сегодня установил CLion. Не могу собрать проект. Ругается на CMake profile.

Вот такие ошибки получил:

```
/home/andrey/Документы/programs/clion/CLion-2018.3/clion-2018.3/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/andrey/CLionProjects/SpiralMatrix
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/andrey/CLionProjects/SpiralMatrix/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

[Previous CMake output restored: 05.12.18 17:26]
```

Как исправить? Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: не прилагайте скрины!!! Вместо этого вставте в вопрос то, что вывело в лог. Если, конечно, хотите получить хоть какой-то ответ

Comment: Ответы ниже конечно занятны, что бы не было установленного make - это надо постараться. Для начала я просто бы попробовал ручками собрать, обычно это делается так `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && cmake --build .`. Если не соберется - тогда печаль. А если соберется - выбросить clion на помойку (я это уже сделал)

Comment: @KoVadim Плохой совет. В логе написана команда, которая не эквивалентна той, которую вы привели. Если вы "выбросили clion на помойку" из-за того, что не смогли собрать проект, то виноват не `CLion`. Если по другим причинам, то зачем об этом сообщать под этим вопросом?

Comment: Команда, которую я привел -  это стандартная рабочая команда. Она по умолчанию использует makefile. В моем случае, cmake в консоли собирал во всех возможных видах (make, ninja). А CLion не хотел. И не хотел потому, что искал make не там, где он есть.

Comment: В моём случае было решено исправлением CMakeLists.txt, а именно - добавлением `add_executable(outputExe inputSrc.cpp)`

Answer (score 5):

Понимаю что вопрос старый, но считаю необходимым ответить для следующего кто будет искать.

Ошибка *"cannot find any CMake profiles"* - это внутренняя ошибка CLion, она говорит о том, что вам необходимо настроить профиль для сборки. Профиль в CLion - это замена аргументам командной строки, которые нужно было бы передать при сборке через консоль. Обратите внимание, что CMake **уже входит в поставку CLion**, так что вам не нужно устанавливать его отдельно - если только вы не хотите использовать другую версию.

Зайдите в меню `File -> Settings...`, в нем выберите вкладку `Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake`. На этой странице вы можете создать и настроить профиль сборки точно так же, как это делается из командной строки (это хорошо описано в документации самого CMake). По-умолчанию там уже есть один профиль, **Debug**, но если ваш проект требует дополнительных настроек для сборки (например указания пути к какой-то сторонней библиотеке), то CLion не сможет сгенерировать проект с текущими настройками, и выведет довольно путающую ошибку "cannot find any CMake profiles" (хотя технически профиль есть).

**Обратите внимание:** хотя меню `Settings` хранит глобальные настройки, настройки профиля сохраняются отдельно для каждого проекта, т.ч. изменение профилей не помешает сборке других ваших программ.

Что касается следующих ошибок:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

Они говорят о том, что у вас не настроен toolchain, т.е. набор компиляторов и утилит для сборки, из-за чего текущий профиль не может быть использован.

Если вы используете Linux, или если вы используете Windows и у вас уже установлена Visual Studio - CLion должен был сам найти подходящий компилятор. Вы можете проверить это, открыв вкладку `Toolchains` рядом с той, в котороый вы настраивали профили.

Если компилятор действительно не настроен, я советую вам посмотреть вот эти инструкции по настройке: [Quick Tutorial: Configure CLion on Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC).
Для Linux воспользуйтесь инструкцией по установки компилятора для вашего дистрибутива. После настройки toolchain вам нужно будет зайти в текущий профиль, и выбрать его в качестве используемого - это исправит ошибки.

Также советую вам ознакомиться с документацией по самому CMake, и с циклом статей на русском языке на Хабре:
[Официальная документация CMake](https://cmake.org/documentation/) (на английском)
[Полное руководство по CMake](https://habr.com/en/post/431428/) (статья на русском)

Answer (score 2):

Коллеги, я не понимаю, почему на вполне корректный вопрос такая негативная реакция.
я бы хотел ответить более благожелательно и подробно.

1) Ошибка говорит о том, что IDE CLion не может найти утилиту Cmake.
Когда Вы устанавливали CLion - там в процессе установки был экран, на котором установщик проверяет наличие разных tools для работы ide. То есть, (в отличие от Visual Studio) среде разработки CLion нужны еще некотрые программы на Вашем компьютере для полноценной работы. И на одном из шагов установки об этом сообщаелось.
Это две важные штуки - компилятор и CMake.
Если вы испольузете Ubuntu, то устновка того и другого довольно элементарна:

```
sudo apt install g++
```

- это установка компилятора. 
  Проверка его версии:

  g++ --version

Установка CMake:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

Проверка того, что он установился (и версии)

```
cmake --version
```

Если Вы используете Windows, то Вам надо посмотреть ресурс
https://cmake.org/download/
и оттуда скачать и установить CMale по инструкции. Скорее всего, все будет работать, главное - прописать путь до исполняемых файлов CMake в системном path системы Windows

2) Второй очень важный момент.
Когда Вы создаёте проект в CLion - он в проект включает зависимости и скрипты для сборки. Если в момент создания проекта в системе не было CMake, то эти скрипты в проекте - неправильные. И они не исправятся сами по себе после установки CMake. Самый простой способ борьбы с ошибкой в этом случае - после установки CMake заново создать проект.

Успехов вам.

Answer (score 1):

Написано прямым текстом, что у вас нет (или нельзя найти) программы `make`, чтобы собрать сгенерированные `Makefile`. Установите или укажите явно путь к ней.

Либо генерируйте не их, а что-то другое. Вероятно, проекты visual studio в вашем случае, раз компилятор есть.

Answer (score 1):

Вам вполне ясно сообщается в выводе: `CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles"`. Тобишь у вас нет программы, которая могла бы собирать файлы, которые сгенерит `cmake`. Вангую, что у вас `windows` а раз так, то никакие не `Unix Makefiles` а по крайней мере `MinGW Makefiles`. А вообще для этих целей существуют генераторы - и для `Clion` я уверен тоже есть. Посмотреть их все можно запустив `cmake` с флагом `-G` и выберите нужный.